# How to get data displayed from a sql select function on the same page using php

Tags: php, sql, forms, select

I'm creating a page which needs to be able to search a database for a specific piece of information, if found i need it to display on the same page after you hit search. i will be using postcodes to run the search, so if someone has left details before i can punch in their post code and select them if they are there. i am using primarily php and dont know much else, is this possible? ive got the database set up and the add function/form.

Now i am just after a search function is this possible in php? and preferably on the same page?

I believe I may need it to be something like

```
  // Connect to server and select databse.
  mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
  mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

  $sql="SELECT * FROM customer
  WHERE postcode=''"
```

And this should display them no? after it displays i need an option to highlight the one i want, then once highlighted when select is pushed it takes me to a new page with this information.

ok so ive worked it to be something like this i think

```
  // Connect to server and select databse.
  mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
  mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

  $sql="SELECT * FROM customer
   WHERE postcode = VALUES
  ('$_POST[postcode]'";

 if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
     die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
    }

     mysqli_close($con);
   ?>
```

This will display it i hope but i dont know what other part of the if i need or if i should even have that if statement?

Comment: For that, you can go for `Ajax` and `jQuery` concepts..

Comment: You are mixing (deprecated) `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions. This will not work.

Comment: ok, how would i go about making it work? im not 100% clued up on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend AJAX for the job. You can find sample code here:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp
The "showHint()" function can be anything of course in your app.

Comment: thanks but i dont think thats what i need, it needs to search my database for existing entries, then display these and then allow me to select the one i wish?

Comment: yes, you would have a dynamic div on your page, when you run your query, the output would show up in that div, but the rest of the page would remain unchanged. that's what ajax is for